# Waterline - REST response missing instance methods

Tags: json, sails.js, waterline, instance-methods

When calling an instance of a waterline object via REST, the response does not contain any of the the instance methods defined in the waterline model. I read somewhere that when the object is written to JSON it strips off any methods. How can I stop this from happening? How can I make these instance methods available for usage in my front-end framework?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I stop this from happening?

You can't.

> How can I make these instance methods available for usage in my
>   front-end framework?

You have to write actions that wrap the model instance methods and call them from your frontend.